# Strange script behaviour in new versions of firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, firefox

I recently got tasked with doing some upgrades to an old customer portal. It ran on some old libraries such as jq1.3.2 so you can imagine when the site was tested it was found not working on current versions of some browsers inc IE (using edge engine) and Firefox. I have since updated jq version to 1.9.0 and got it working for all versions of IE and Chrome with a jq migrate patch as $.browser was coming up not defined (removed in jq 1.9) and this is used across the site.

Current Firefox still won't load the site, other browsers will accept the patch for $.browser and load the script as expected as seen in the console by logging but Firefox seems to load script files twice in a single load/refresh and in erratic order so my guess is the $.browser migrate patch doesn't get loaded in at the right time so it still finds it to be undefined. After some trial and error I found that this started with version 41, 40.0.3 is fine and loads the site perfectly with the console showing correct logging order but as soon as 41+ is installed BOOM. Below are screenshots of the behaviour showing from each versions console:

**Firefox 40.0.3 (current chrome and IE):**

[image]

**Firefox 41+:**

[image]

**KEY:**

0 start - $.broswer patch migrate script load

0 end - $.broswer patch migrate script finished

1 start - jQueryUI1.7.2 script load

1 end - jQueryUI1.7.2 script finished

-1 - script in head load

**Script calls in head:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/newTree/jquery.browser.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js"></script>
```

There are errors showing about Kaspersky but I have tried to disable it with no change so just ignore that. Anyone any ideas on what is happening with these new versions of firefox, is it something to do with new HTML5 compliances?